# timeout with protractor, what triggers this one, and how to fix?

Tags: angularjs, protractor, timeout, e2e-testing

Angular version: 1.5.8 / 
protractor version: 5.2.2

What I am actually doing on the page, I am clicking a button for a chart to load..

I am actually able to see the element on the page...

```
- Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
      at ontimeout (timers.js:466:11)
      at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:304:5)
  - 
Failed: Timed out waiting for asynchronous Angular tasks to finish after 36 seconds. This may be because the current page is not an Angular application. Please see the FAQ for more details: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#waiting-for-angular
  While waiting for element with locator - Locator: By(css selector, .fullscreen-close-btn.visible).
```

Basically, as much as I could google this, this is related to angular

```
 The following tasks were pending:
       - $timeout: function (){var b;if(m=null,!a.equals(q,l)){b=a.copy(l),a.forEach(q,function(c,d){a.isDefined(c)&&"$"!==d[0]&&(p.setItem(e+d,f(c)),delete b[d])});for(var c in b)p.removeItem(e+c);l=a.copy(q)}}
```

**I can't seem to understand what triggers this. As far as I could dig on google about this, the only thing that I can find related to this is:**
[this](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/789).

How can I fix this?

**UPDATE**

The bellow issue was caused by ngStorage library! There is a fork for replacing the $timeout from that fork...

https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage/issues/246

However, my issue it's not fixed. It's failing in the exact same point, with the exact same error, except the $timeout line is now gone.

Comment: Could you try adding browser.ignoreSynchronization = true; to your spec temporarily

Comment: did not work.. there are about 400 tests, and that was triggered in loads of places

Answer (score 0):

`$timeout.flush();` is what you need.

Comment: in angular?  in protractor ?

Comment: when you run angular from browser it makes $timeout.flush() on every digest cycle, in protractor it doesn't happen, so you have to run it manually, exactly has $httpBackend.flush()

Comment: there's also [`browser.waitForAngular()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.waitForAngular): 

> Instruct webdriver to wait until Angular has finished rendering and has no outstanding $http or $timeout calls before continuing.